# How to install pygame on msys2?

Tags: python, pip, pygame, msys2

I want to install pygame 1.9.6 on msys2 using pip for python2.7. The problem is that i'm getting an error when i try to install it with 'pip install pygame'.

This is the error:

```
Processing d:/msys64/home/desolaser/pygame-1.9.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:


    WARNING, No "Setup" File Exists, Running "buildconfig/config.py"
    Using WINDOWS configuration...


    Download prebuilts to "prebuilt_downloads" and copy to "./prebuilt-x64"? [Y/n]Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:/users/desola~1/appdata/local/temp/pip-req-build-tn9xwt/setup.py", line 194, in <module>
        buildconfig.config.main(AUTO_CONFIG)
      File "buildconfig/config.py", line 210, in main
        deps = CFG.main(**kwds)
      File "buildconfig/config_win.py", line 576, in main
        and download_win_prebuilt.ask(**download_kwargs):
      File "buildconfig/download_win_prebuilt.py", line 303, in ask
        '\nDownload prebuilts to "%s" and copy to %s? [Y/n]' % (download_dir, dest_str))
    EOFError: EOF when reading a line

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:/users/desola~1/appdata/local/temp/pip-req-build-tn9xwt/
```

I tried doing the same in python3 with 'pip3 install pygame' but i get the same error.
It is possible to install pygame on msys2?

Answer (score 0):

I had this error as well. You can install it from a wheel file.

First install wheel into python using pip.

pip install wheel

Go to this page
https://pypi.org/project/pygame/#files
or
https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame

They have built wheel files for pygame for 32 and 64 bit, depending on which type of python you have installed. So for 32-bit python version 3.7, on windows,   you would download
pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37-win32.whl

Then install the wheel file

pip install C:/some-dir/pygame-1.9.6-cp37-cp37-win32.whl

Comment: Can you add a bit of detail?